# Broken python virtualenv after git push and git pull

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I have a python based local repository and It has a `env` (virtualenv) in it. I'm able to "activate" this `virtuanenv` with standard source env/bin/activate and run my python program. I have made sure that this repository is updated on remote as well with `git push origin master`.

Now, I executed `git pull origin master` on the server. It got the env and all the updates. I also (just to be extra sure) did `git fetch --all` followed by `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Accoring to my understanding after this the server should have exact same `env` as my `localhost`. Now when I run `source bin/env/activate` and followed by `type python` I get following:

```
python is /usr/bin/python
```

Surely I'm missing something here. I'm unable to understand this. **Please Help!**

Comment: Why do you store a virtualenv in the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put the virtualenv in the repository.  There are binaries in there, and they won't run on different systems.

What you want to do is put `requirements.txt` in your repo with all the packages you'll need, then create a new virtualenv on a new machine and do `pip install -r requirements.txt` to get all the packages your app needs.